# Code Stage To update Collection value

Tags: c#, collections, blueprism

Im trying to use a code stage to loop through a collection i have that contains one column. With each iteration the value in each row in will be updated.

Any help on this would be great appreciated

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: need to explain in details with example what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the term code stage but a simple for loop should work. I would use this if your data set isn't large.

```
 foreach (var item in collection)
   {
    // do your stuff   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more details:
So i have an input collection in my code stage(input_collection) in Blue Prism. This collection contains one column with 1000's of rows. These items are dates and need to be manipulated in some way with each loop. 
So far ive something like this:

```
//input_collection is input. 
//Loop is set up to loop though each item in input_collection.

    for (int i = 0; i < input_collection.Rows.Count; i++)

    {

            collection.Rows[i][0] = "New Date Example";


    }
```

What i expected this code to do was loop through the entire collection and update each row(in this case to "New Date Example"), but having no luck so far.

Comment: You should edit your post with this information instead of providing it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your update, I think you are just referencing your variable wrong. Replace the line:

```
collection.Rows[i][0] = "New Date Example";
```

with:

```
input_collection.Rows[i][0] = "New Date Example";
```

Edit:
Your code may be easier to read if you implement a for each loop as suggested by Dallas:

```
foreach (DataRow row in input_collection.Rows) {

    row.FIELDNAME = "New Date Example";

}
```

Where `FIELDNAME` is the name of the single column of the collection you have defined in Blue Prism.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, this was just a typo.

Looks like i was forgetting to output the collection data at the end of the code stage.

Output_collection is referencing the same collection as input collection.

for (int j = 0; j < input_collection.Rows.Count; j++)

{

input_collection.Rows[j]["First_Detected"] = "Testing";

}

**Output_collection = input_collection;**

Thanks for the help